# Set the default value in the Dockerfile for php.ini

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Default value (local value)

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket
```

is null.
I want to address Dockerfile when it comes up
[image]

My DockerFile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN apt-get -y update \
        && apt-get install -y libicu-dev \
                libxml2-dev \
                libzip-dev \
                libpng-dev \
                libwebp-dev \
                libjpeg-dev \
                libxpm-dev \
                libfreetype6-dev \
                libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
                zip \
                unzip \
                nano \
        && docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-webp --with-jpeg --with-freetype \
        && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
        && docker-php-ext-install mysqli intl pdo pdo_mysql soap opcache zip gd bcmath sockets

COPY ./ioncube_loader_lin_7.4.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902
RUN docker-php-ext-enable ioncube_loader_lin_7.4.so
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

You are installing but not enabling it.
Please add additional RUN command into your Dockerfile:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

As stated from documentations, PHP extensions need to be both installed and enabled: https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Comment: thank you for answer. additional this command but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

first create the custom-php.ini and set value such as:

```
[php]
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Then we add this file to Docker
example

```
ADD ./custom-php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom-php.ini
```